# storing for loop variables as vector

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vector

I have some values that I would like to store as a vector or array so that I can output it into a table.

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
xCenter = 50;
yCenter = 50;
theta1 = 0 : 0.314159 : 2*pi;
radius = 25;
x1 = radius * cos(theta1) + xCenter;
y1 = radius * sin(theta1) + yCenter;
plot(x1, y1);
axis square;
xlim([0 100]);
ylim([0 100]);
grid on;

r=25; %distance between centerline of drive axle and the ICR
l=2; %distance between wheels on drive axle
xcenter=50
ycenter=50

for theta1=0:pi/10:2*pi
    theta1 
    thetadot=theta1/1 %thetadot is the angular velocity so theta gets divided by 1 second.
    x1=r*cos(theta1)+xcenter
    xdot=x1/20 %xdot is the velocity, so the distance x gets divided by 20 seconds

    y1=r*sin(theta1)+ycenter
    ydot=y1/20 %ydot is the velocity, so the distance y gets divided by 20 seconds

    Rtheta=[cos(theta1) sin(theta1) 0; -sin(theta1) cos(theta1) 0; 0 0 1]

    XIi=[x1 y1 theta1]

    %Velocity in the global frame
    XIidot=[xdot ydot thetadot]

    %Velocity in the local frame
    XIrdot=XIidot*Rtheta
end
```

Now, I am unsure how to store the values from theta1, XIidot and XIrdot into vectors so I can output them to a table. I am already using a for loop defined from the steps in theta1, so how would I get it store those three values into vectors?

I want to have the table formatted so that theta1, XIidot and XIrdot are each their own column. Like this:

```
         theta    XIidot    XIrdot
         _____    ______    ______

Position1    38       71        176   
Position2    43       69        163   
Position3    38       64        131   
Position4    40       67        133   
Position5    49       64        119
```

I have tried searching for an answer but all the questions I could find don't seem similar to mine.

Thanks in advance for the help.

David

Answer (score 0):

```
theta = [0:pi/10:2*pi];
XIrdot = zeros(..., length(theta));
XIrdot = zeros(..., length(theta));
for i=1:1:length(theta)
    theta1=theta(i);
   ...
   XIidot(:, i) = .....
   XIrdot(:,i) = ......
end
```

Either vectorize the whole loop, or do it ugly like this.

Answer (score 0):

Your physics doesn't make sense, so I'd look at that as well.

$ x = r cos \theta $

$ \dot{x} = \dot{r} cos \theta - r sin \theta \dot{\theta} $

So you cannot define both $\dot{theta}$ and $\dot{x}$

But to the question you asked.

All you need to do is convert theta1 from a loop to a vector. The only place where a loop is at all necessary is when you're doing your rotation matrix and even there if you wanted to think about it you could probably get rid of that as well.

```
xCenter = 50;
yCenter = 50;
theta1 = 0 : 0.314159 : 2*pi;
radius = 25;
x1 = radius * cos(theta1) + xCenter;
y1 = radius * sin(theta1) + yCenter;
plot(x1, y1);
axis square;
xlim([0 100]);
ylim([0 100]);
grid on;

r=25; %distance between centerline of drive axle and the ICR
l=2; %distance between wheels on drive axle
xcenter=50;
ycenter=50;

theta1=reshape(0:pi/10:2*pi, [], 1);

thetadot=theta1/1; %thetadot is the angular velocity so theta gets divided by 1 second.
x1=r*cos(theta1)+xcenter;
xdot=x1/20; %xdot is the velocity, so the distance x gets divided by 20 seconds

y1=r*sin(theta1)+ycenter;
ydot=y1/20; %ydot is the velocity, so the distance y gets divided by 20 seconds



XIi=[x1, y1, theta1];

%Velocity in the global frame
XIidot=[xdot ydot thetadot];
XIrdot = zeros(size(XIidot));

%Velocity in the local frame
for i = 1:length(theta1)
    Rtheta=[cos(theta1(i)) sin(theta1(i)) 0; -sin(theta1(i)) cos(theta1(i)) 0; 0 0 1];
    XIrdot(i, :)=XIidot(i, :)*Rtheta;
end

table(theta1, XIidot, XIrdot)
```